# quiz about bit related topics

Tags: algorithm, numbers

```
i have following  quiz:
 Let x be an integer larger than the odd number q.  Change the value of x using the following rule 
    if  x  is even 
      then  x / 2 
      else  x – q 
    until x becomes smaller than q
```

If the final value of x is zero, what can you say about the original input value? 
I am thinking about one thing: if x is odd or x=2*k+1 and we are subtract also odd number, we get even. Also I want to note, that unless x is power of 2, at some step dividing by 2, we get odd number. Let take q=11; x>11;let's take x=23; because x=23 is odd, we will have x=x-q  x=23-11=12; now x is even so we will have x/2=6<11, so here we can't determine which value of x is about,but if x=22, then we will have x=x/2=11   x=11 is odd, so we will have x-q=0--> it means that x is multiple of q, but which one odd or even number? Let's take x=33; x is odd so x=x-11=22  it is even  x=x/2=11, it is odd so x-q=0; no does it means that x is multiple of q?

Comment: Just so you know, by about 3 lines in, i was hearing Charlie Brown's teacher.  Surely you learned to write better than this...

Comment: @cHao agreed this seems as if it was at one stage on one line then auto wrapped by the editor.

Comment: Probably typed on a touch-screen phone during a "bathroom break" from a mid-term exam. :)

Comment: no midterm,i am preparing  by myself

Comment: Actually a power of two also eventually becomes odd through division by two, namely one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is apparently that x is multiple of q.